# My employer withdrew money from my HSA. What recourse do I have?

Tags: hsa

I have had constant issues with my employer and HSA contributions.

They mistakenly withdrew money from my HSA account.  All my HSA contributions are employee contributions, taken out of my salary.  They did not return the withdraw to me.

What recourse do I have?

Comment: when did this happen? 2020 or 2021? Is it possible that they were removing money that shouldn't have been deposited? More details are needed? Is the information of the W-2 accurate?

Comment: What country do you work in? Your options may be different depending on the location.

Comment: @JohnFx how many countries have *literally* the HSA?

Comment: I don't know about "The HSA" because it just means Health Savings Account. But after further research just the US and Singapore apparently. I would have expected more countries would have some version or another of this concept.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the USA you could file a complaint on your employer with the Department of Labor.

There is information available on [their website here](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/contact/complaints) for how to do that.